# Is there any way to extract a transform matrix from a view matrix in glm?

Tags: c++, matrix, glm-math

I need to extract the transform matrix from my camera to assign it to a mesh.

I'm working in a computational graphics project in school, the objective is to simulate the arms of a character in first person perspective.

My camera implementation includes a vector3 for the camera position, so i can assign that to my mesh, the problem is that i can't extract the rotation of the camera from my view matrix yet.

I calculate my final pitch and yaw in the rotation function this way, x and y are the current mouse position in the screen

```
m_yaw += (x - m_mouseLastPosition.x) * m_rotateSpeed;

m_pitch -= (y - m_mouseLastPosition.y) * m_rotateSpeed;
```

This is how i update the view matrix when it changes

```
glm::vec3 newFront;

newFront.x = -cos(glm::radians(m_yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(m_pitch));

newFront.y = sin(glm::radians(m_yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(m_pitch));

newFront.z = sin(glm::radians(m_pitch));

m_front = glm::normalize(newFront);

m_right = glm::normalize(glm::cross(m_front, m_worldUp));

m_up = glm::normalize(glm::cross(m_right, m_front));

m_viewMatrix = glm::lookAt(m_position, (m_position + m_front), m_up);
```

Right now I can assign the position of the camera to my mesh, like this

```
m_mesh.m_transform = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), m_camera.m_position);
```

I can assign the camera position successfully, but not rotation.

What i expect is to assign the full camera **transform** to my mesh, or to extract the **rotation** independently and assign it to the mesh after.

Comment: What is `VECTOR3`? GLM has no such type. Also: "*the problem is that i can't extract the rotation of the camera from my view matrix yet*" Why do you need to? Didn't you create the view matrix *using* the "rotation of the camera"?

Comment: Sorry, a VECTOR3 is just a typedef for an glm::vec3, i already edited that.

And yes, i know i build the view matrix with a rotation, but i just don't know how to create a transform matrix with those 3 vectors or my pitch and yaw independently.

Note: i tried to assign my view matrix to my mesh transform and the result was that the rotation was kind of inverse, maybe the view matrix is inverse to the transform?

thanks.

Comment: yup, i know, that code is not the problem, i meant glm::vec3, i just did a typedef for the glm vec3

Comment: If you try to rotate the 'camera' clockwise, objects will appear to move counter clockwise. Draw a square on a piece of paper, look at it, then tilt your head right. Which way did it appear to 'move'? Is there a reason you are performing the trig yourself instead of using glm::rotate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much for your answers, they helped a lot.

I managed to solve my problem in a very simple way, i just had to directly assign the final transform to my mesh using the separate properties of my camera.

glm is so new to me, i wasn't familiar with the way it handles matrix multiplications.

The final code takes a translation matrix with the camera position, then i rotated the resulting matrix in the Y axis with my pitch and finaly the resulting one rotates in the X axis with my yaw.

```
m_mesh.m_transform = glm::rotate(glm::rotate(glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), camera.m_position), glm::radians(-camera.m_yaw), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)), glm::radians(-camera.m_pitch), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
```

Answer (score 0):

The steps to setting up the model view projection matrix, that I have always followed (which doesn't mean it's 100% right), which appears to be what you are having problems with is:

```
// Eye position is in world coordinate system, as is scene_center. up_vector is normalized.
glm::dmat4 view = glm::lookat(eye_position, scene_center, up_vector);
glm::dmat4 proj = glm::perspective(field_of_view, aspect, near_x, far_x);

// This converts the model from it's units, to the units of the world coordinate system
glm::dmat4 model = glm::scale(glm::dmat4(1.0), glm::dvec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0));
// Add model level rotations here utilizing glm::rotate

// offset is where the objects 0,0 should be mapped to in the world coordinate system
model = glm::translate(model, offset);
// Order of course matters here. 
glm::dvec3 mvp = proj * view * model;
```

Hope that helps.